# Setting AD Groups into a session from StartUp.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm having issues trying to pass data around. I have a startup.cs file that that gets a user information from graphclient and I filtered the groups that a user should pertain in the application from Azure AD. The code as follows in startup:

### Startup.cs

```
// above code gets key vaults and db connection

services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                    {
                        options.Instance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(EnvironmentSecrets.AADInstance));
                        options.Domain = domain;
                        options.ClientId = clientID;
                        options.TenantId = tenantID;
                        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                        // This causes the signin to prompt the user for which
                        // account to use - useful when there are multiple accounts signed
                        // into the browser
                        options.Prompt = "select_account";

                        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        {
                            var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                                .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

                            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                                {
                                    var token = await tokenAcquisition
                                        .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, user: context.Principal);
                                    request.Headers.Authorization =
                                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                                })
                            );

                            // Get user information from Graph
                            User? user;
                            try
                            {
                                user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                                    .Select(u => new
                                    {
                                        u.DisplayName,
                                        u.Mail,
                                        u.UserPrincipalName,
                                        u.MailboxSettings
                                    })
                                    .GetAsync();
                            }
                            catch (ServiceException ex)
                            {
                                // If it's not a mailbox enabled user, just skip the mailbox aspect of this.
                                if (ex.IsMatch("MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI") || ex.IsMatch("ResourceNotFound"))
                                {
                                    user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                                        .Select(u => new
                                        {
                                            u.DisplayName,
                                            u.Mail,
                                            u.UserPrincipalName
                                        })
                                        .GetAsync();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw;
                                }
                            }

                            context.Principal?.AddGraphClaimsInfo(user);

                            var group = await graphClient.Me.TransitiveMemberOf
                                .Request()
                                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                                .GetAsync();
                            IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> allADGroups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group));
                            IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> relevantADGroups = allADGroups.Where(t => t.DisplayName?.Contains("StartUp") == true);

                            this.SetGlobalParams(relevantADGroups);

//Other Code

private void SetGlobalParams(IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> groups)
        {
            Global.Groups = groups;
        }
```

The global params is a class that I have as a static class and as follows:

### Global.cs

```
public static class Global
{
    public static IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> Groups { get; set; }
    //Other fields
}
```

With the following code on top I get the relevant groups that I get for that particular user. There's is 2 groups that from like hundreds that match string StartUp. What I want to do is to filter a dropdown menu that should have two companies that are 'StartUp' based companies out of a hundred that a user is in. What I want to do is set this list of two companies that are 'StartUp' and put it into a session so then I can manipulate it as I want to but I'm getting hunged up on executing it. Any ideas?

Also I am aware that setting it into a Global.Groups doesn't really help because we set it but it can only be used in StartUp file.